# How to store the value of a cell from grid view to database using the select command?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Select")
            {

                GridViewRow gv = GridView1.SelectedRow;
                Session["m_email"] = gv.Cells[3];
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
                con.Open();
                string insert = "insert into Service_Info values(@c_email,@email,@first_name,@last_name,@contact,@licenseno,@street,@landmark,@pincode)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_email", Session["user"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",Session["m-email"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", Session["user"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", Session["user"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", Session["user"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@licenseno", Session["user"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@street", StreetText.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@landmark", LandmarkText.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pincode", PincodeText.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Label6.Visible = true;
                Label6.Text = "Successfull...";
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

[image: I got this error when i used the code]

I want to store the value of a cell from the grid view to the database. I only want to store only the email cell value not all from grid view. But I am not getting a way to do so.

Comment: Is `gv` null? or is `gv.Cells[3]` null? Once you get that working you'll actually want `gv.Cells[3].Text`

Comment: The docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow?view=netframework-4.7.2) suggest using the `CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged` event

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir. Actually when I tried to display the cell value in a label, it's working all well. But when I tried to store the value in database its giving me the error. So, that's why I am not getting exactly what to do?

Comment: Your error is saying that either `gv` or `gv.Cells[3]` is null - which is it? Set a breakpoint and check. Unless Session is null but that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Select")
            {
                  int selectedRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                  GridViewRow gv = GridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex];

                  // Rest of the code
            }
         }
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your help. As I implemented it another error popped up. ........String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated. At Line 73:                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: This error indicates that the length of one your table columns is less than the data you are trying to insert into it. Please check the length of columns in your `Service_Info` table.

Comment: @TazimShaikh If your issue is resolved, you can close this thread